# WebDriverException: Message: Missing 'marionetteProtocol' field in handshake

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, selenium-grid, firefox-marionette

I'm currently trying to run a robotframework test scripts locally (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit). The issue that I faced was not able to launch FF browser in Open Browser. Below is the details/specs of the setup that I have.

- **Firefox (v26.0)**
- **Selenium2Library**
- **selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar**
- **geckodriver-v0.9.0**

Please note that I used same machine as hub and node (selenium grid)

Here the command to launch my **hub** :

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role hub -port 4444
```

While here's the command to register my **node** :

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -trustAllSSLCertificates
```

I did what is per told in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver (add wires executable in the PATH)

I also did :

```
${ff default caps}    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].common.desired_capabilities.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX    sys,selenium.webdriver
Set To Dictionary    ${ff default caps}    marionette=${True}
Create Webdriver    Firefox    executable_path=\home\my\wires
Open Browser   ${HOMEPAGE}  ff  None  ${HUB}
```

As a result, the FF browser launch, but not opening the URL ${HOMEPAGE}. I've been googling around and stuck in this issue for so long. Please help..

Comment: from where are you fetching the value of `${HOMEPAGE}`?

Comment: I fetch it from the variable that i defined on the same file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

- firefox version is too low , update to 48 is OK
- python 2.7
- selenium  3.0.1
- geckodriver  v0.11.0.exe
- firefox 48.0

Comment: Updating Firefox fixed the issue for me on OSX.