# Getting Connection refused error when run robotframework testscripts in Selenium Grid

Tags: robotframework, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver

Continue from previous thread. ([WebDriverException: Message: Missing 'marionetteProtocol' field in handshake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38991440/webdriverexception-message-missing-marionetteprotocol-field-in-handshake))

I've upgraded my browser version to FF 48. The browser launched but unable to navigate to the website that I specify.

WebDriverException: Message: Connection refused Stacktrace: at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect (PlainSocketImpl.java:-2) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182) at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect

Updated specs:

- Firefox (48.0)
- Selenium2Library
- selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
- geckodriver-v0.9.0

Does anybody managed to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find the solution for my selenium setup.Thanks to this guy.http://learn-automation.com/use-firefox-selenium-using-geckodriver-selenium-3/

I downgraded my FF to v45.0.2 to make it work with selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar and installed the following specs :

1. selenium = v2.44.0
2. robotframework-selenium2library = v1.8.0
3. robotframework = v3.0
4. robotframework-seleniumlibrary = v2.9.2

The issue that I faced also due to the existence of selenium 3 eggs in the dist packages (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages). So after removing the egg, selenium works and browser launched as expected.